# How do I secure my firestore for anonymous access of product data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using FireBase / Firestore for my website - I have products displayed on the website which are stored in the database. - Currently, I am having my rules set up as

```
 match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true
      allow write,create,update, delete: if request.auth.uid !=null
}
```

I am getting now mails from Firebase warning me about my insecure rules:

```
[Firebase] Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules

    We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
any user can read your entire database
Because your project does not have strong security rules, anyone can access your entire database. Attackers can read all of your data, and they can drive up your bill.
```

How do I secure my database properly but allow my website to read product data withour requiring the visitor to sign in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email is warning you that anyone can read any document in your entire database because of `match /{document=**}`.  You should avoid using this global wildcard entirely, since it can lead to unexpected security issues.  You should instead call out each individual collection with specific access for that collection.  Minimally, it will look more like this:

```
match /collection1/{document=**} {
    allow read: if true
    allow write,create,update, delete: if request.auth.uid !=null
}

match /collection2/{document=**} {
    allow read: if true
    allow write,create,update, delete: if request.auth.uid !=null
}
```

Whether or not this form is "proper" for your app is not clear.  Your rules need to encode the specific permissions **for your app**.  Every app is going to be different, and your rules need to be tailored to your security requirements.  You are effectively writing application logic into the rules, so treat it just like any other code.